# Problems running scala/play project with Docker

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, docker, docker-compose

I have a multi project SBT build. One of the sub-projects is a Play project. Normally, I'd run `./activator "project website" run` to run the Play project. I'm trying to setup a docker development environment, but having trouble getting a proper `CMD` in my Dockerfile. I'm trying to use docker compose as well. My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM java:latest
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
CMD ["./activator", "\"project website\"", "run"]
```

I escaped the quotes in `"project website"`. When I run `docker-compose up` to start this up, my project dependencies download, but then it fails with:

```
wb1_1 | [warn] there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
wb1_1 | [warn] two warnings found
wb1_1 | release stage is set to: stage
wb1_1 | [info] Set current project to root (in build file:/code/)
wb1_1 | [error] Expected letter
wb1_1 | [error] Expected symbol
wb1_1 | [error] Expected '!'
wb1_1 | [error] Expected '+'
wb1_1 | [error] Expected '++'
wb1_1 | [error] Expected 'debug'
wb1_1 | [error] Expected 'info'
wb1_1 | [error] Expected 'warn'
wb1_1 | [error] Expected 'error'
wb1_1 | [error] Expected ';'
wb1_1 | [error] Expected end of input.
wb1_1 | [error] Expected '--'
wb1_1 | [error] Expected 'show'
wb1_1 | [error] Expected 'all'
wb1_1 | [error] Expected '*'
wb1_1 | [error] Expected '{'
wb1_1 | [error] Expected project ID
wb1_1 | [error] Expected configuration
wb1_1 | [error] Expected key
wb1_1 | [error] Expected '-'
wb1_1 | [error] "project website"
wb1_1 | [error] ^
services_wb1_1 exited with code 1
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to run inside my container?

Comment: The quotes are on the command-line used to pass `project website` as one argument. You don't actually want to pass them to activator. As a side note, you can do `activator website/run` since Play 2.4

Comment: @dwickern ugh. I'm stil using 2.3.8

Comment: @dwickern do you have a recommendation if I'm not using 2.4?

Comment: Have you tried removing the escaped quotes?

Comment: @dwickern using `website/run` worked. Has nothing to do with Play version apparently. Can you post as answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: It was fixed recently anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our comment thread, you can use `CMD ["./activator", "website/run"]`

Comment: Apparently this wasn't so simple. If I run my project that way, none of my Actions work. I get `Action not found, no router defined` for all routes.

Comment: You could try my original advice (remove the escaped quotes) or upgrade to Play 2.4